# Precision of SVD in solving Least Square goes against theory

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, svd, numerical-calculus

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{100\times100}$ (with $\operatorname{rank}(A)=100$) and $b\in\mathbb{R}^{100}$, the goal is to solve for $x$ :

> $$
> \|b-Ax\|_{2}=\min_{y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}\|b-Ay\|_{2}
> $$using SVD.

### SVD Approach

The SVD is known to be the most stable in finding least-squares as compared to QR and Cholesky. The approach goes by defining the economic version of SVD that is  $A=U_{r}S_{r}V_{r}^{T}$ where $U_{r},S_{r},V_{r}\in\mathbb{R}^{100\times 100}$, then the least-square problem can be reduced to solving the following normal system :
$$
S_{r}V_{r}^{T}x=U_{r}^{T}b
$$
and this can be done as follow :

> $1.$ Compute $c=U_{r}^{T}b$

> $2.$ Find $w$ in $S_{r}w=c$.

> $3.$ Find $x$ in $V_{r}^{T}x=w$.

### Experimenting goes Against Theory

After writing a MATLAB algorithm to compute the least-square of $A$ and $b$ with both $A$ and $b$ being randomly generated, then executing it, I received the vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{100}$. However the issue began to arise when I computed the norm $\|b-Ax\|_{2}$ to determine the stability and shockingly it appeared to be less precise ($\sim 6\times 10^{-16}$) than when I computed the least-square of the same $A$ and $b$ using QR which turned out to be $\sim 3\times10^{-16}$ which is about twice as precise as SVD approach which made me wonder why this happened.

### The Question

> How could this be interpreted knowing the following information I gathered:

> - $\operatorname{cond(A)}\sim 10^{3}$
> - $\|A\|_{2}=\sigma_{\max}(A)\approx 100$
> - The least three singular values of $A$ where $\sigma_{1}=0.1885, \sigma_{2}=0.0580,$ and $\sigma_{3}=0.0128$.

> I was wondering if singular values has to do anything with the precision whether the scale of their values can affect the accuracy of $x$ since it was supposed to be that SVD is most stable in solving least-squares problems.

Side Note : The algorithm that I wrote involves using MATLAB's built-in SVD function using its economic version. Therefore, everything in my algorithm is optimized.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "computing the norm to determine stability"? Where exactly did the number $6 \times 10^{-16}$ come from?

Comment: Also, your usage of big-O notation doesn't really make sense. If you want to say that a number is approximately $10^3$, write $\sim 10^3$, not $\sim O(10^3)$. Big-O notation is about order of growth, which has nothing to do with the approximate value of a particular constant.

Comment: Perhaps the following explains what you have found: as $A$ varies, the solution to the optimization $\min_y \|Ay - b\|$ changes discontinuously whenever the rank of $A$ (the number of non-zero singular values) changes, but is otherwise continuous.

Comment: Computing the norm $\|b-Ax\|_{2}=6\times 10^{-16}$ is the error in approximating $x$ in solving the least-square problem since in theory in actual theory this norm would be $0$ since we would be solving the system $Ax=b$ but since computers are accurate up to epsilon machine then this norm can not be $0$. The number $6\times 10^{-16}$ came from executing the matlab code $norm(b-A*x)$. I wrote an algorithm that solves the least square using QR and the norm computing was half of the norm computed for SVD @BenGrossmann

Comment: I have edited the post to remove the big O notation, I apologize I am still learning computational mathematics. @BenGrossmann

Comment: That is not what "stability" usually refers to in this context. I would bet that since your error is on the order of Matlab's "epsilon", this error is likely completely explained as an artifact of floating point arithmetic, which in this context is essentially random (i.e. it won't necessarily be smaller for the SVD method than for the QR method).

Comment: I suspect that the difference between the SVD and QR methods (as measured by the resulting $\|Ax - b\|$) would only be noticeable in cases where $A$ has at least one singular value equal to zero (i.e. $A$ does not have full rank).

Comment: I thought $\epsilon=\|b-Ax\|_{2}$ in MATLAB would give an estimate of the precision/stability of $x$. In the case of SVD as we know it must be more stable than QR in solving least-square problems even thought its more expensive but computing the norms in these two cases gave me unexpected results since I thought computing the norm would estimate the range of stability of the method used @BenGrossmann

Comment: "Precision" and "stability" are very different concepts; it seems like you're interested in "precision".

Comment: I have thought about rank-deficient matrices since it is known that SVD works best at them and I tried that on MATLAB the norm was in order of $10^{-2}$ far better than QR, Cholesky... but in this case with square matrices I was surprised to see QR outpace SVD in stability (or precision if that would be the accurate term when computing $\|b-Ax\|_{2}$ on MATLAB @BenGrossmann

Comment: As it seems I have confused these two terms together I would hope for more explanation @BenGrossmann

Comment: "Stability" in this context typically refers to how the solution $x$ that is obtained by the algorithm changes as $b$ changes. It might also to refer to how $x$ changes as the entries of $A$ change.

Comment: Alright now it because clear so we have to graph $x$ as it varies with $b$. Therefore my question revolves around precision of SVD. I shall update my post @Benn Grossmann

Comment: If you want and if you are not busy, we can take this conversation to the chat :) @Ben Grossmann

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127441/discussion-between-read-my-bio-pls-and-ben-grossmann).